# foreach() error in my php template when trying to relate two tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, inner-join

I´m reading Kevin Yank´s book "[PHP and MySQL Novice to Ninja 5th edition](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/phpmysql5/)", and found an error there in the code, and would like someone to help me out with it, maybe is a silly typo...?

I´m trying to follow the author´s example of creating and accessing a database of jokes. I´m learning how to join two databases to show with php a list of all the jokes.
I have two databases joke and author.
I´ve got this:

```
try{ 
    $sql = 'SELECT joke.id, joketext, jokedate, name, email
    FROM joke INNER JOIN author
    ON authorid = author.id';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $jokes[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'], 
    'text' => $row['joketext'], 
    'date' => $row['jokedate'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'email' => $row['email']
    );
}
include 'jokes.html.php';
```

Now, all was working ok, until I´ve replaced the simple code to select the database information from just one table, to the INNER JOIN code.
This is the book´s code, wich I´ve followed.

In the jokes.html.php file, I´ve got this (wich I think is what´s giving me the error):

```
    foreach($jokes as $joke): 
      <form action="?deletejoke" method="post">
  <?php 
      echo 'id. ';
  echo htmlspecialchars($joke['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  echo htmlspecialchars($joke['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
  echo htmlspecialchars($joke['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      echo htmlspecialchars($joke['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['id'];?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Borrar">
  ?>
  <br></form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, the error that throws me is:

Notice: Undefined variable: jokes in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace1\jokes.html.php on line 10

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace1\jokes.html.php on line 10

Line 10 of jokes.html.php is:

```
foreach($jokes as $joke):
```

I´m trying to get more information about foreach() but I can´t spot the error...
If anyone could help me out a bit (or maybe a clue!) I would be very grateful.
Thanks!!! 
Rosamunda

**UPDATE:**

As the result of the query (trying it directely from phpmyadmin) was zero, so there were no database results for that query. I´ve decided to manually add one result doing this:

```
INSERT INTO joke SET
joketext = 'this is a new joke....',
jokedate = '2012-01-01',
authorid = 1;
```

Now, the errors have dissapear, and that single results does show.

What I don´t understand is:

***Why didn´t just no result showed up, instead of those errors?***

***How do you manage these situations? I mean, it can happen that a query just have no results at all, is it common to result in those errors?***

***One of your helpful comments says that $result is empty... so why when the query isn´t zero those errors won´t show up?***

Thanks again for your help!!! Rosamunda

Comment: Can you run the SQL straight in the database, and see if it works?

Comment: What is the output if you run `print_r($jokes);` right after your `foreach ($result as $row)` loop?

Comment: Try echoing the SQL and then copying/pasting into the database to see what the resultset looks like.

Comment: This might not solve the problem but try giving aliases to your tables like SELECT joke.id, joketext, jokedate, name, email
    FROM joke j INNER JOIN author a
    ON j.authorid = a.id

Comment: It sounds like `$result` is empty. Just before your `foreach($result...` loop, `print_r($result);` ... You are never initializing the `$jokes` array, and if your query result is empty, it will never be set, thus the notice that you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I´ve tried running the SQL in phpmyadmin and it works fine. print_r($jokes); results in 2 errors: == Notice: Undefined variable: jokes in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace1\jokes.html.php on line 10
== Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace1\jokes.html.php on line 10

Comment: I almost forgot: when I try the INNER JOIN directely in the database, it doesn´t  get any errors, but the result is zero, I mean, no results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve found the answer in a [SitePoint forum (the Book´s forum)](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?866328-Example-in-Kevin-Yank%B4s-book-won%B4t-work-(involves-INNER-JOIN-and-foreach())-page-151&p=5149876#post5149876), and I thought that it would be nice to post the question here, just in case anyone wonders, or just in case anyone out there happens to have the same problem.

> It is because of your php settings to show Notices and Warnings. The
>   notice/warning is valid because you were attempting to use the $jokes
>   variable before you declared/assigned a value to it. You can solve
>   this by putting `$jokes = array();` before  PHP Code:
>
> ```
> foreach ($result as $row) 
> { 
>     $jokes[] = array( 
>     'id' => $row['id'],  
>     'text' => $row['joketext'],  
>     'date' => $row['jokedate'], 
>     'name' => $row['name'], 
>     'email' => $row['email'] 
>     ); 
> }
> ```
>
> That will at least declare the $jokes variable for in the event that
>   there are zero results.

So, I think the conclusion (please correct me if I´m wrong here!) is that **you should always declare any variable that you pretend to use, just in case it happens to have no results. Because if it is empty it will show a nasty error message that will freak you out.**

And to declare a variable you use `$variablename = array()`.